# How to store fetched data from API to Global Variable

Tags: javascript, validation, performance-testing, global, fetch-api

As seen in this picture, I have initialized variable madhu globally and assigning the fetched data to this variable inside `.then` method but it's showing me undefined.
How can I store this value globally?
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tegOp.png)

Comment: please while asking a question, also include the code with which you are having problem with and what you have tried so far.  You are using variable before its initialization.

Comment: Instead of adding a picture showing the code snippet in question it is best to include it in the question, marked as a code fragment. The advantage of this method is that others can directly copy and paste it to a site like jsfiddle or include it in their own internal test arena to find out what's going on instead of having to type it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between synchronous and asynchronous code. The value is setting correctly as in line 160 after response is received but line 167 runs before 160 and at that time the value was not set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different options.

The simplest is using localStorage already in the HTML5, you could save the data in the browser

```js
localStorage.setItem('response', JSON.stringify(data));
myData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('response'));
```

sorry my english is not very good, I hope I have explained myself well

Comment: This unfortunately won't resolve the issue with the error in line 167. The problem is that the log statement is executed right after the fetch has been issued - however, the .then handlers in question only run after the fetch has returned.